# Having trouble understanding the logic of this infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

What makes this an infinite loop? Shouldn't `n` reach 5 and terminate the loop?

```
int main()
{

    int n = 1;
    while (n <= 5)

    cout << n ;
    n++;

}
```

Comment: A proper indentation would help you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f309338c53842b13

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot when i follow the link i see a blank page

Comment: @tobi303 just wait a little, with infinite loop from program, it takes a time to load

Comment: Corrolary: **Always** use curly braces with `if`, `while`, `for`. **ALWAYS.** While not doing so is not an error *per se*, errors are not far off. Personally, I take it a step further and use `{ /* EMPTY */ }` even for, well, *empty* loops. It might look like a nuisance at first, but it just flat-out avoids issues like this one. "A `while` without `{}`. Let's put them in there... *ooooh...* found a bug."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There are no curly braces after the `while` condition**.

That's why only `cout << n;` is executed *over and over again*. When you write `while (something) doThis(); doThat();`  or `if (something) doThis(); doThat();`, *only `doThis()` gets executed while (or if) `something` is true*.

If it was written like this

```
int n=1;

while (n<=5) {
    cout << n;
    ++n;
}
```

Then it wouldn't be infinite

Answer (score 3):

Because your code is equivalent to

```
int main()
{

    int n = 1;
    while (n <= 5)
    {
      cout << n ;
    }
    n++;

}
```

`n++` will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the value of `n` wouldn't get incremented (unless control is out of loop). This is because the `n++;` is not a part of the loop. This is the reason why it becomes an infinite loop.

Use `{ }` to indicate block of code when there is more than one statement.

Make the following change:

```
while (n <= 5) {      
   cout << n;      
   n++;    
}
```

In the above code, `n++;` is a part of the loop and the value of `n` increments with every iteration and finally the control moves out of the loop when `n` is 6.

**Note:** The loop does not terminate when `n` is 5. It terminates when `n` is 6 since you are asking the loop to run when `n<=5`. So it will run even when `n` is 5.